# How should you store multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch

Couldn't find how Numpy and PyTorch store arrays (tensors), so I'm asking here.

If you need to store multidimensional arrays like those two, should you store all values in a single-contionuous array and store the shape of the array to determine how you parse it (which is also beneficial when reshaping the array), like the following `int arr[];`, or should you store the multidimensional array as is, so for example storing a 2d integer array like so in C for example: `int arr[][];`.

Which should be the way for maximum performance and memory efficiency?

Also, any reference on how to go on developing such a thing is appreciated.

P.S That's for a school exam, so no libraries.

Comment: See the NumPy docs for [Internal memory layout of an ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#internal-memory-layout-of-an-ndarray).

Comment: What do you mean by "store"? Are you asking how multi-dimensional arrays are implemented? In `numpy`, they are implemented as contiguous arrays.

Comment: A numpy array stores values in a flat contiguous 'c' array, and uses `shape`, `strides` and `dtype` attributes to interprete, index, and iterate over it.  Operations like reshape, transpose, and slice (index with a regular pattern) are fast since they don't normally require copying any data.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Indeed, thank you for the help.

Comment: @hpaulj That explains it, thank you.